# Accordion Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I know I keep putting out these troubleshooting things, but I seriously have researched this on api documentation and looked for other answers on Stackoverflow and nothing is coming up. I have a accordion div that takes the right css, but is not working as an accordion. This is html code:

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion">
<ul>
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header">Page One</h3>

    <div>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#1a">Subpage 1A</a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#1b">Subpage 1B</a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#1c">Subpage 1C</a>

        </li>
    </div>
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header">Page Two</h3>

    <div>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#2a">Subpage 2A</a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#2b">Subpage 2B</a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#2c">Subpage 2C</a>

        </li>
    </div>
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header">Page Three</h3>

    <div>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#3a">Subpage 3A</a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#3b">Subpage 3B</a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-accordion-content"><a href="#3c">Subpage 3C</a>

        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

And my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#accordion').accordion();
});
```

And Finally here is my css for the elements shown:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
margin-top: 2px;
padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-noicons {
padding-left: .7em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-icons {
padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
position: absolute;
left: .5em;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
padding: 1em 2.2em;
border-top: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mherPresident/VAw52/1/) example:

Please review and help me know how to get this collapsing and expanding.

Answer (score 0):

your html markup is wrong check out http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ (view source)

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>Section 1 body</div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>Section 2 body</div>
</div>
```

you have an extra `ul` tag inside the main container

updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Exlord/VAw52/5/)

Comment: I have headers and divs (with elements inside them) what exactly am I getting wrong. I have read the accordion and the only thing I can think of is to make every content div have its own <ul></ul>

Comment: It looks like adding <ul> Tags inside the content headers was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had only one

combination. I needed to put the a combination in each content div like so:

```
<div class="ui-accordion-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a><!--Content goes here--></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have corrected it and you can see the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mherPresident/VAw52/6/).